# How to create download link for qr code image in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, qr-code

I am using Laravel 5.2 and **[Simple QR code](https://www.simplesoftware.io/docs/simple-qrcode)** library for creating QR code. It works fine. Now i want to download generated QR code. Inspect element shows: [image: This] I can save this image, *right click on image>save image*. But i want to make a link so that i can download this image with clicking download link button. Same as: **[this](https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/)**

mycode for creating qr code:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(100)->generate('helloworld')) !!} ">
    <p>Scan me to return to the original page.</p>
</div>
```

Output of QR code: 
[image]

Is there anyone who can help me regarding this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: first you need to convert base64 to png

Comment: @BilalAhmed its output already in png format if i save it right click on image>save image. Look the output in the updated question.

Comment: i have add answer with details check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might looking for download image of QR Code after generating a QRCode as image [download](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_a_download.asp)

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

Or you can fixed filename

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="filename">
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking something like this.

Answer (score 0):

First decode on base64 then save into directory and finally show in image tag

```
file_put_contents('yourImgeName.png', base64_decode($dataString));
```

Finally

show image into `img` tag

```
<img src="yourImgeName.png" />
```

if you want  to directly download image then used this

goto jsfiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VmGLF/1/)

Comment: I don't want to save into directory. I want to download this image directly. Same as this https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/ website.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud use jquery and i have add link of jsfiddle

Comment: dear, why you creating image? It already created. Now i want to create just download link of that image. So that i click on download button and image is downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Myabe you can try using headers, telling browser or forcing browser to download the file

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
header("Content-length: " . filesize($NewFile)); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $NewFile . '"'); 
echo $content;
exit();
```

Where $NewFile can be your image file which gets generated.
Or try changing image/jpeg to your suitable extensions.

Comment: You can see my code and inspect element. what will be the $FileName and $NewFile for that?