# File download not working in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5, download

I have stored a file in `/public/storage/attachment` and the file has a `hashname` which is stored in my database as well in the `attachments` table `filehashname` column

```
public/attachment/N52lbwmzubAcgUfHYhCC4A6NFBniIVmK.pdf
```

In the view I'm displaying the file as a link so that when the user clicks the link the file gets downloaded.

```
<a href="{{ URL::to( '/download/'.$post->attachments[0]->filehashname) }}">
   {{ $post->attachments[0]->filename }}
</a>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/download/{filehashname}', 'PostController@downloadAttachment');
```

PostController

```
public function downloadAttachment($filehashname)
    {
        $file= public_path('/storage/attachment/'.$filehashname);

        return response()->download($file, 'demo.pdf');
    }
```

But this does not download the file it opens the URL `http://localhost:8000/download/public/attachment/N52lbwmzubAcgUfHYhCC4A6NFBniIVmKfctqMNOq.pdf` with `Page Not Found`

If I hardcode the filename and click the link then it downloads but dynamically passing the name of the file in url gives Page Not Found error.

How to solve this?

Comment: does file exit in folder ?

Comment: yes, it does. And it works when i store file with name abc.pdf in folder and give path directly in the controller as $file= public_path('/storage/attachment/abc.pdf'); but it does not work when i pass filename in the URL

Comment: your file is saved in public folder or storage folder ?

Answer (score 1):

If your file is stored in public directory then try **public_path()** and if your file is saved in  storage directory then try **storage_path()**

```
$destination = storage_path('storage/attachment/'); // if your storage folder contains only attachement folder then like this :- storage_path('attachment/');
               or
$destination = public_path('storage/attachment/');
$pathToFile = $destination.$filehashname;
return response()->download($pathToFile,'demo.pdf');
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `downlaod` option in anchor tag

```
<a href="{{ URL::to( '/download/'.$post->attachments[0]->filehashname) }}" download >
 {{ $post->attachments[0]->filename }}
</a>
```

This is being answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558605/how-to-create-download-link-for-qr-code-image-in-laravel/46559827#46559827)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$myFile = public_path($filehashname); # place file in public/ and check this; 
# If works add this public_path("storage/attachment/".$filehashname);
$headers = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];
$newName = "demo.pdf";
return response()->download($myFile, $newName, $headers);
```

[`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-public-path)