# QR code redirect to website using Milon Barcode Library

Tags: laravel, qr-code

I want to redirect after scan or just to show button redirect to website in Milon, How to do that?

```
{!!DNS2D::getBarcodeSVG('https://www.facebook.com/' , 'QRCODE',3,3)!!}
```

if i scan the barcode, just show https://www.facebook.com/ with type text

is that possible here like https://www.qrcode-monkey.com? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: To clarify, you are asking if it's possible for the device that scans the QR code to automatically get redirected to the QR code location?

Comment: no @apokryfos, i think like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558605/how-to-create-download-link-for-qr-code-image-in-laravel but using library milon barcode